# Iyun sefarim on Taharos

Tags: product-recommendation

Are there any *Iyun* sefarim on Taharos, either by topics or on the Mishna?

I am not looking for the commentaries printed with the Mishna.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/20463

Comment: Taharos the Seder or Taharos the Masechta?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I am looking for a sefer on the concepts in Seder Taharos. Something like [Mikdash Dovid](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/14562) (and when I went to get this link, I see that he also has on Taharos, not just Kodshim.)

Comment: Not sure why this is closed as opinion-based, I think its pretty objective if a sefer is *iyun* and if its on Taharos. Anyway, thanks all for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider the following:

[Rav Yaakov Ades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Ades) has a sefer called [Divrei Yaakov](https://hebrewbooks.org/55117)

[Rav Yaakov Chagiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Hagiz) has a sefer called [Eitz Chaim](https://hebrewbooks.org/30651)

Comment: Chazon Nachum...

Comment: @kouty thanks. https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/21269

Answer (score 0):

Rav Michel Feinstein has a set of sefarim on Taharos. There is also Sidrei Taharos.

Comment: Do you know the name of Rav Michel Feinstein sefarim?

Comment: It was something basic like Shiurei R' Michel if I remember correctly. The Steipler also has sections on Taharos in Kehillas Yaakov I think.